# Hazalcast_kubernetes plugin setup through hazelcast-context.xml with tcp-ip enabled

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I want to configure [hazelcast-kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes) through hazelcast-context.xml

My configuration is:-

```
<hz:network port="${com.example.hazelcast.network.port:5741}" port-auto-increment="true">
    <hz:outbound-ports>
        <hz:ports>${com.example.hazelcast.outboundports:0}</hz:ports>
    </hz:outbound-ports>
    <hz:join>
        <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
        <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <hz:members>${com.example.hazelcast.network.members:127.0.0.1}</hz:members>
        </hz:tcp-ip>
    </hz:join>
</hz:network>
```

I want to configure hazelcast-kubernetes in existing configuation.

```
 <hz:kubernetes enabled="true" />
```

As per the [JoinConfig](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/config/JoinConfig.java) class, We can not enable two configuration. How Should I configure it without modifying existing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Hazelcast configuration using system properties or environment variables. Please check [Hazelcast Docs: Overriding Configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/configuration/overriding-configuration-settings.html) for more details.